# Is it possible to Host single website on multiple server?

Tags: web-hosting, php, apache, server, dedicated-hosting

I have a file sharing website . It's hosted on a dedicated server which have 16gb RAM and 2tb storage . Now I need more storage and RAM but my hosting service can't provide more than 2tb on single machine . Can I host this site on 2 server with another 2 Tb storage . Will I get 4tb storage for my site . I'm using apache as a server , MySQL for database and php for server side language .

Comment: No. Not they way you are describing it. It sounds like your host is using 1U servers preconfigured and will not stray from the plat plan they have already. It should be otherwise trivial to provide a computer with at least 18terabyte in a raid on a 4U chassis. You can possibly look into using a CDN to host your images. That may be your best bet.

Comment: All big site host their site on multiple server but it uses [load balancing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_(computing)) to serve specific request.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to host a single website on multiple servers?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/23437/how-to-host-a-single-website-on-multiple-servers)

Comment: @Goyllo The OP is not looking for load sharing or fail over but rather splitting the content of the site across two servers. This is not practical giving the OPs description. It is possible, just not practical. The OP would find the growth unmanageable. Cheers Mate!!

Comment: @Deepaksharma As it's written, this appears to be a duplicate of the linked question. Based on the community's response, it's unclear however if you plan on splitting up your data between servers or duplicating it for redundancy. If you can edit the question to clarify that, and so that's it's substantially different from the linked duplicate question, it will be considered for reopening.

Answer (score 1):

Its better you can use AWS EFS Service or S3 to store your contents. If you still want to go with same and need solution then you can take another small server with 2TB HDD and install NFS to mount that HDD in your existing Server. So, You can able to use 4TB HDD from existing machine.
Let me know if you need further help on this.

Comment: Kudos! I forgot about NFS. Cheers!!